# IntelliJ won't let me import an existing Scala class

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am currently developing an online multiplayer game in Scala where game content is separated from the core (engine) on the server-side. This is done through a multi-project build using SBT.

While refactoring code I wanted to move things around and re-organize all of my source files. However, when I moved majority of my files one package up, things started breaking and IntelliJ wouldn't let me import an existing trait from the core module anymore.

I have provided a GIF recorded with Gyazo illustrating the issue:
[here](https://i.gyazo.com/fe5230d751ee767797fe25c59a31fbfd.mp4)

I have tried the following things to solve the issue but nothing worked:

- Run 'sbt clean' in command line
- Close and re-open project solution in IntelliJ
- Restart IntelliJ with the "Invalidate Caches" option

Update: [Here's](https://i.gyazo.com/3ed8807372c5558312c118937c308188.png) a screenshot of my package tree.

Comment: why don't you manually add this line `import rogue.core.game.extension.GameExtenstion` ?

Comment: I did and it doesn't work either. It acts as if it can't be found.

Comment: it would be helpful if you update with tree structure of your projects packages.

Comment: I have fixed the problem. It was because IntelliJ created a conflict with all package notations inside classes within a specific package, causing all files to act up. This is because I use a package object located at the root `rogue.extensions` package. Thanks.

Comment: great to hear that :) you can post your answer below :) it would be helpful for all of us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem. It was because IntelliJ created a conflict with all package notations inside classes within a specific package, causing all files to act up. This is because I use a package object located at the root package `rogue.extensions`.

Comment: note you can mark your own answer as accepted, so that people looking out for unanswered questions will know they don't need to worry about this one :)